# 60 balls to be distributed among 3 people such that C gets more balls than B and B than A

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

In how many ways can you distribute 60 balls among 3 people such that the number of balls that C has is more than B and B has more than A.

(i) Can this question be rephrased as in a group of 60 people, A,B,C are a few. In how many of the total arrangements does C come before B and B comes before A ( left to right or right to left doesn't matter right?) ?

So my approach for the original question is as follows:

In 1/3rd of total arrangements C will have more balls than A and B , and in 1/2 od total arrangements B will have more balls than A. So the answer is 1/6th of total arrangements.

Total arrangements is non-negative solutions of a+b+c=60, which comes out to be choosing 2 from 62 I.E. $62 \choose2 $

So the answer is $\frac{62 \choose 2}{6}$ , but the answer so obtained is wrong. The actual answer is 300.

Can you guide me along the right process of thinking?

Comment: The problem is that you think that in the $\binom{62}{2}$ arrangements, there are six disjoint cases depending on the order of $A,B,C$. This is unfortunately not true, since if you are doing a partition like : $\{A>B>C\}, \{A > C>B\},...$ and so on, then you *miss* some cases. On the other hand, if you are partitioning via $\{A \geq B \geq C\}, \{A \geq C \geq B\}$ and so on, then you have overlaps between the sets. So while you did get the total number $\binom{62}{2}$ right, you need to remove the "bad" cases to apply the first type of partition, where you can divide by six.

Comment: So  do I need to manually count how many cases are there where C>B and B>A are not satisfied and then subtract them from the total? I mean there would be a lot of cases to count manually right?

Comment: Yes, but can we find a quick way to eliminate the bad cases? Let us think.

Comment: Ok so if I am not wrong, there is 1 case where A=B=C = 20. 30 cases where C > (B=A).  But how to find cases in which C>B but B<A ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define three new variables as below:

The number of balls A has = $x$

The number of balls B has = $x+y+1$

The number of balls C has = $x+y+z+2$

We are going to find the number of solutions to $3x+2y+z+3=60$ in which $x,y,z$ are bigger or equal to zero. Actually, we have $3x+2y+z=57$.

First, suppose $z=3m$ so  $y$  must be $3n$, so we will have $x+2n+m=19$. We can put numbers instead of $n$. The number of answers in this case follows $20+18+...+2=110$.

Second, suppose $z=3m+1$ so  $y$  must be $3n+1$, so we will have $x+2n+m=18$. We can put numbers instead of $n$. The number of answers in this case follows $19+17+...+1=100$.

Third, suppose $z=3m+2$ so  $y$  must be $3n+2$, so we will have $x+2n+m=17$. We can put numbers instead of $n$. The number of answers in this case follows $18+16+...+2=90$.

Therefore, the total number is $110+100+90=300$.

Comment: I like this approach, can you please explain how did get this part : "The number of answers in this case follows $20+18+...+2=110$."

I get that n can vary from 0-9, but thats not what you have done here right?

Comment: @RayPenber  when we put $n=0$, $x+0+m=19$ is obtained, which has $20$ solutions. when we put $n=1$, $x+2+m=19$ is obtained, which has $18$ solutions and so on.

Comment: That's a really nice method for translating this type of partition problem into a linear equation in the natural numbers!

Comment: Thanks, I got it :)

Comment: @Rajaei can you answer the other question which I had asked ? If the question was to find the number of arrangements in which C comes before B and B comes before A , would the answer be the same?

Comment: @RayPenber First give an order to the arrangements, for example from left to right. Then think in this way: you have 60 empty places. Each of the 60 people occupies one place. Separate A,B and C from the other. Pick three places for A,B and C. In how many ways you can pick these three places? Next, in how many ways you can put the other 57 people? And, in how many ways you can put A,B and C in the three picked places? I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, thanks for explaining.(Have just started with combinatorics, so have a lot of mundane doubts)